# JQuery banner drop down - animation is jumpy and end 32 pixels too high

Tags: jquery

Our question pertains to a jQuery animation at this location:

http://www.simalam.com/leeanderson/profile/

Click on the drop down arrow to see the animation... and click on the pull up arrow to close the banner. Now that you have seen it, I can describe better what the issues are.

The animation is jumpy near the bottom, and ends in the wrong position (specifically 32 pixels too high). It begins in the right spot though.

We have tried switching the -32 and 0 in every possible combination. The only combination that gives us the animation we like is 0 0 for both if statements. However we don't like the 32 pixel white border underneath individuals and organizations.

If anyone has any suggestions, they would be greatly appreciated.

**Here is the code applied to it:**

```
/* code for dropdown of menu */
$("#dropArrow").click(function () { //with every click, the arrow should rotate
    value += 180; //for every click, add 180 degrees, so that it goes back to either pointing up or down with each click
    if ((value % 325) == 0) { //(hide) before hiding the .topDivSlideWrap, we do this first and restore css settings to default
        $( ".drop" ).css("top", "-0px"); //move .drop back to original positioning
        $( "#individuals" ).css("z-index", "0"); //remove z-index of #individuals
        $( "#organizations" ).css("z-index", "0"); //remove z-index of #individuals
    }   
    $('.topDivSlideWrap').slideToggle('slow', function() {;
    if (value % 325) { //(show), this is set in a callback function so it happens after slideToggle
        $( ".drop" ).css("top", "-32px"); //move .drop up to hide whitespace
        $( "#individuals" ).css("z-index", "1000"); //add z-index of #individuals
        $( "#organizations" ).css("z-index", "1000"); //add z-index of #individuals
    }
    });
    $('#rotate').rotate({  //function within a function
        animateTo:value,easing: $.easing.easeInOutCirc //rotate 180 degrees every time 
        });
});
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any animation issues in Safari.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of issues to address in order to place the slider working.

See this working [Fiddle Example!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/694zQ/)

## 1)

You function to control the slide and rotation can be significantly reduced to this:

```
// reset variable
var value = 0;

$("#rotate").bind("click", function(e) {

    // prevent browser's default behavior
    e.preventDefault();

    // increment value to control rotation
    value+=180;

    // rotate arrow
    $(this).rotate({
        angle     : 0,
        animateTo : value,
        easing    : $.easing.easeInOutExpo
    });

    // slide contents
    $(".topDivSlideWrap").slideToggle("slow");

});
```

## 2)

The `#individuals` and `#organizations` have a `css` `top` declaration, update it to `0`, it is forcing the content to go way below the containers height:

```
#individuals, #organizations {
    top:0;
}
```

## 3)

The background image used with the gray degrade has a white space on the bottom, with the size of 31px in height, that is causing the illusion that your div is taller than the background. You will need to fix that image.

*Here you have a fixed one, right click and save.*
[image]

---

With those two changes, as seen on the working Fiddle example, you have your problem solved!

Comment: Awesome thank you! Your help was really appreciated now, we managed to get the drop down working smoothly!

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance! Since you have your problem solved, please tick the answer to close this topic. _(tick is on the left side of my answer)_

Answer (score 0):

It's not the jQuery your main issue, but the position you applied originally to the slider element in your CSS. What you need to fix is : if you animate the `top` position - make sure it is well defined in your CSS and will not override the `margin-top`. Just play around this properties and you'll fix your issue. OR: (in your jQuery code) instead of animating the `top` position, try with `margin-top`. But again, Arr that values must be originally defined in your CSS to prevent (e.g.) Safari browser not to animate your element.

---

Some other suggestions to 'minify' your code:

Use the comma to list your elements:

`$( "#individuals, #organizations" ).css("z-index", "0");` //remove z-index from the list of elements.

`$( "#individuals, #organizations" ).css("z-index", "1000");` //add z-index to list of elements

`if (value % 325) {` This is like you said e.g.: `if( 1 + 2) {` just with Modulus (it has no meaning)

Than you have a strange typo:

```
$('.topDivSlideWrap').slideToggle('slow', function() {;  // <-- what is this??? (;)
```

Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I applied them and things are working now!